# C# If statement for SQL

Tags: c#, if-statement

I am using WinForms and I want to use SQL if statement in my code.

Here is a small example. I am using SQL long query and I want to use IF statement to do two different functions. Here is example.

```
string query = 
    "SELECT U1.UserID,
            U1.FirstName,
            U1.LastName,
            C1.UserID,
            C1.FriendID
     FROM USERS U1
     INNER JOIN Chat C1 ON U1.UserID = C1.UserID
     WHERE C1.UserID = '" + MyName.Uid + "'
       AND C1.FriendID = '" + friendid + "'
       OR C1.UserID = '" + friendid + "'
       AND C1.FriendID = '" + MyName.Uid + "'
     ORDER BY C1.ChatID";
```

There is some more stuff in there. But here is what I need. I know this gonna be wrong, I need someone to help me to write correct if statement.

```
if (C1.UserID = '" + MyName.Uid + "' and C1.FriendID = '" + friendid + "') {
    // some code.
}
```

Comment: In my if statement example is exact criteria I am trying to find in if statement.

Comment: Oh, I totally understand. I was trying simply use an SQL query as if condition.
I was trying few options but non of these options didn't work. At least you can give me an advice?

Comment: You can't use an SQL query as an if statement. You can, however, query data from a database, and use the data you have obtained to make a decision using an if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use use SQL Query this way.
First you have to execute your query to get data from database. Once you have it, you can do your if statement to get what you wanted.
And for your if statement you should use Equals to test strings equality.

```
if (C1.UserID.Equals(someString)  && C1.FriendID.Equals(anotherString))
{
    //some code.
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will do some more research on this. Thank you for advice

Comment: You're welcome and you should also take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ado-net-code-examples to know how to query from database

Comment: Page not found :)

Comment: Thank you, it does!

Comment: Amazing, it worked just as I expected. Thank you. Now I know how to set if statement based on SQL query.